# What tools are available to build a custom media player?

Tags: audio, streaming, video-streaming, html5-video, audio-streaming

In essence, I need to develop a media player with several "Play" buttons, one for each file type.

See detailed information here:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1809376

Which of the streaming technologies would you recommend and why?

TIA

Comment: Nothing. I am an experienced programmer but would not know where to start. Let me give you an example: my applications create/edit PDF and Excel files but I would be nuts to attempt to do that from scratch. Some sort of library and environment is required.

Comment: You should always include the details in the question body instead of redirecting to a separate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried searching?

Web:

[SoundJS](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS) supports Web Audio API / HTML5 audio / Flash.

[Howler.js](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/) supports Web Audio API / HTML5.

[MediaElement.js](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/) supports H.264 in mp4 over HTML5 with a Flash fallback.

Standalone:

[libav](https://libav.org/)
[FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)

to name a few.

Comment: DO they have the ability to add your own buttons?

Comment: "Have you tried searching?" Indeed. I am searching in StackOverflow. Your response is a hit.

Comment: Most are skinnable so you don't even need a custom player. You can just embed 2 distinct players with the same graphics and load them accordingly:   eg. one for the .wav and one for the .mp3 and .mp4.